# Store check box value as bit in DB

Tags: c#, .net, database

Hi i have a checkbox and in code behind i insert the value from checkbox into the DB. This is what i did:

```
   ClassRegInfo order1 = new ClassRegInfo
    {
        classID = classID.Text,
        ObtainedPermission = Convert.ToByte(obtainedPermission.Checked)}
```

Obtained Permission in DB is of type bit. So when I do the above step, i get an error:

```
  Cannot implicitly convert type byte to bool
```

So, can u let me know how to store the value as a bit in DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont convert it to byte. Bit equals Bool

```
ClassRegInfo order1 = new ClassRegInfo
{
        classID = classID.Text,
        ObtainedPermission = obtainedPermission.Checked
}
```

Comment: can u let me know how i can store it in db

Comment: Is this Linq2Sql or what? How do you usually save data to the database?

Comment: What does your class look like? It is probably just to make the database column a bit and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL to accept a boolean, I got this to work

```
Convert.ToInt32(checkbox.Checked)
```